# Too many FTP connection causing Error 421

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I'm using oXygen XML editor, and after a certain period of time I get "**Error: 421 There are too many connections from your internet address.**"

I can see that oXygen is creating a bunch of ftp connections, but I'm not sure how to kill the connections or make oXygen stop. I'm running Ubuntu 9.10. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the FTP server then you can try and force the max number of connections to be unlimited (by default it is limited to 50 connections)

With VSFTPD you add

`max_per_ip=0`

into the /etc/vsftpd.conf file and restart the service.

However, I am not sure that this will fix your problem. I have had the same issue with oXygen and the only thing that works is usually to kill the tcp connections manually. This gets pretty frustrating but will work:

```
sudo tcpkill -9 -i <network-interface> host <host-of-your-ftp>
```

So for example if you had your network interface at eth0 and you were connecting to example.com

```
sudo tcpkill -9 -i eth0 host example.com
```

To get a list of your network interfaces you can do

```
sudo ifconfig
```

Typically its eth0 for hard wired and wlan0 for wireless bit you should double check.

Hope this helps. If you find another solution to this please let me know.

Cheers,

Casey